# AllowColumnResize at client side using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, telerik-grid, radgrid

How to set AllowColumnResize=true at  client side using javascript in master pages using the CSS selector , so that it would apply to all the grid specified with .

My effort-

```
 function pageLoad()
    {
        var grid = $find(".ScrollGrid");
        var columns = grid.get_masterTableView().get_columns();

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) //
        {
            columns[i].resizeToFit();
        }
    }
```

But not successful .Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long debugger mode searching , finally my friend found the property -

```
grid.get_masterTableView()._owner.ClientSettings.Resizing.AllowColumnResize=true;
```

so no need to loop around, a single line can do the trick

```
function pageLoad()
{
    var grid = $find(".ScrollGrid");
    grid.get_masterTableView()._owner.ClientSettings.Resizing.AllowColumnResize=true;
}
```